# Determining most/least amount of occurrences within subset row & column group in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to find the most and least amount of items within a row / column group in a larger data frame. Here is the data to make it clearer:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 8, ncol = 3))
df$X1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
df$X2 <- c("yellow", "green", "yellow", "blue", NA, "orange", NA, "orange") 
df$X3 <- c("green", "yellow", NA, "blue", "red", "purple" , "orange", NA) 
names(df) <- c("group", "A", "B")
```

Here is what that looks like (I have NAs in the original data, so I've included them):

```
  group      A      B
1     1 yellow  green
2     1  green yellow
3     1 yellow   <NA>
4     2   blue   blue
5     2   <NA>    red
6     3 orange purple
7     3   <NA> orange
8     3 orange   <NA>
```

In the first "group", for instance, I want to determine which color occurs the most and which color occurs the least. Something that looks like this:

```
  group      A      B   most  least
1     1 yellow  green yellow  green
2     1  green yellow yellow  green
3     1 yellow   <NA> yellow  green
4     2   blue   blue   blue    red
5     2   <NA>    red   blue    red
6     3 orange purple orange purple
7     3   <NA> orange orange purple
8     3 orange   <NA> orange purple
```

I am working within a `dplyr` chain in the original data so I can `group_by` "group", but I am having a hard time figuring out a method that allows me to work within a "cluster" of two columns with differing numbers of rows. I do not need this to be done with `dplyr`, but I figured it might be easiest given the usefulness of `group_by`. Additionally, I need the result to somehow remain in the original data frame as new columns. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The strategy is to find the "most" and "least" item and prepare a new data frame. After that, use the `right_join` to merge the original data frame and prepare the desired output.

Notice that during the process I used `slice` to subset the data frame to get the most and least item. This guarantees that there will be only one "most" and one "least" for each group. Nevertheless, it is possible that there could be a tie for each group. If that happens, you may want to think about what could be a good rule to determine which one is the "most" or which one is the "least".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -group, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  count(group, Value) %>%
  arrange(group, desc(n)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(c(1, n())) %>%
  mutate(Type = c("most", "least")) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  spread(Type, Value) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "group") %>%
  select(c(colnames(df), "most", "least"))
df2
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  group      A      B   most  least
  <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1     1 yellow  green yellow  green
2     1  green yellow yellow  green
3     1 yellow   <NA> yellow  green
4     2   blue   blue   blue    red
5     2   <NA>    red   blue    red
6     3 orange purple orange purple
7     3   <NA> orange orange purple
8     3 orange   <NA> orange purple
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I've been modifying it for my original data, and I can modify it like you said to add another column if "tied" ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Reshape to long form and use `summarise` (or `count`) to aggregate, subsetting the `which.max`/`which.min`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                 A = c("yellow", "green", "yellow", "blue", NA, "orange", NA, "orange"),
                 B = c("green", "yellow", NA, "blue", "red", "purple" , "orange", NA))


df %>% 
    gather(var, color, A:B) %>% 
    drop_na(color) %>% 
    group_by(group, color) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    summarise(most = color[which.max(n)], 
              least = color[which.min(n)]) %>% 
    left_join(df, .)
#> Joining, by = "group"
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   group      A      B   most  least
#>   <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 yellow  green yellow  green
#> 2     1  green yellow yellow  green
#> 3     1 yellow   <NA> yellow  green
#> 4     2   blue   blue   blue    red
#> 5     2   <NA>    red   blue    red
#> 6     3 orange purple orange purple
#> 7     3   <NA> orange orange purple
#> 8     3 orange   <NA> orange purple
```

2. Sort a table of values and subset it:

   ```r
   df %>% 
       group_by(group) %>% 
       mutate(most = last(names(sort(table(c(A, B))))),
              least = first(names(sort(table(c(A, B))))))
   #> # A tibble: 8 x 5
   #> # Groups:   group [3]
   #>   group      A      B   most  least
   #>   <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
   #> 1     1 yellow  green yellow  green
   #> 2     1  green yellow yellow  green
   #> 3     1 yellow   <NA> yellow  green
   #> 4     2   blue   blue   blue    red
   #> 5     2   <NA>    red   blue    red
   #> 6     3 orange purple orange purple
   #> 7     3   <NA> orange orange purple
   #> 8     3 orange   <NA> orange purple
   ```

Comment: Tried out the first option and it works for me as well. Thank you!